# How to iterate through ArrayList in Java

Tags: java

I have a List that looks like this:

```
List newMap = (ArrayList) map.get("programs");
System.out.print(newMap); //JSON data
```

On printing the above, I get:

```
[{program_id=PR1, service_ids=[1, 2]}, {program_id=PR4, service_ids=[14, 15]}]
```

Now my question is, how do I iterate through this list and get the values based on the keys? I mean something along the lines of `newMap[0]["program_id"]` and then I should get `PR1`.

Code I've tried:

```
for (Object obj : newMap){
        var temp = newMap[0].get("program_id"); //Can't do this because "Array type expected, found java.util.List"
    }
```

Comment: Please share the structure of your map and is the List returned is of type List<Map>..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `newMap` is a List, you would access an element of it with `newMap.get(i)`.

It appears that each element of the List is a Map.

Therefore, you can get the value of a specific key this way :

```
newMap.get(i).get("program_id")
```

If you want to iterate over the list and get the value for a specific key in each map :

```
for (Map obj : newMap) {
    Object value = obj.get("program_id");
}
```

Note that you shouldn't work with raw types. I only used the raw type `Map` because I don't know the type of the data you store in that Map.

Comment: The data is all strings, so I guess that should work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
newMap[0].get("program_id");
```

Comment: What would the for loop look like in this case? Would it be `for (Object obj : newMap)` or something else?